# WebBrowser integration (without using extension)

Tags: c#, download, intercept

I'm working on a download manager and like IDM, i want to intercept all downloads from the default web browser. IDM doesn't use plugins.

So is there a way to send/receive messages from my application to the web browser ?

I used extensions for Chrome but when i saw that IDM doesn't need it, i wanted to do the same. And i also use Microsoft Edge which doesn't have plugins.